# Yii's updateByPk keeps returning 0

Tags: yii

I'm trying to update my user table, which my code does. but for some reason it keeps executing the else statement.

in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateByPk-detail) it states that `updateByPk` should return the number of rows being updated. Which should be 1. what am i missing here? and how do i check if the table has been updated successfully?

```
if (User::model()->updateByPk($model->id, array("last_login"=> Shared::timeNow())))
{
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity, $duration);
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'success' => url(app()->users->getHomeUrl())));
    Yii::app()->end();
} 
else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Could not update user info', 'code' => 'auth'));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

my table schema is this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` text,
  `postal_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activate` varchar(63) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_reset` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email_verified` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_disabled` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `oauth_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oauth_username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oauth_provider` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oauth_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: before that test whether a record is already present in the table by the method "findByPK"

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan i already do that, in some code above it using this `$model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                 'oauth_id' => $user['id'],
                 'oauth_provider' => $this->defaultAction,
              ));`

Comment: will you post your table schema detail here

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but if you already have `$model` in hand then why not simply `$model->last_login = ...` and `$model->save()`?

Comment: @Jon yup i could. but since i'm new to Yii and frameworks all together just thought i try to understand things. plus my logic was as extra error checking wouldn't harm :P

Comment: set primary key for id in table

Comment: Model can be not updated because `last_login` attribute has not valid value.

Answer (score 1):

You should check $model exits first otherwise updateByPk can return 0

```
if ($model && User::model()->updateByPk($model->id, array("last_login"=> Shared::timeNow())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not specify a primary key. Yet you update by primary key.

You have a few choices.

- Change your table structure to include a primary key
- Use another update method. For example, Update() allow you to pass a criteria object.

Answer (score 0):

Know it's old, but : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

And [Yii1 use rowCount](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/016b4220056ef12c52d54e64c8ca11a5b359b45f/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L338)

Answer (score -1):

Model can be not updated because `last_login` attribute has not valid value. 
Try get model errors (`$model->errors()`) or check model by `$model->validate();`

Why you not implement this as follows:

```
$model->last_login = Shared::timeNow();
if ($model->save())
{
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity, $duration);
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'success' => url(app()->users->getHomeUrl())));
    Yii::app()->end();
} 
else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Could not update user info', 'code' => 'auth'));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: -1. The OP is asking about `updateByPk` which doesn't check validation.

Comment: @topher Why do you think so? I guess he asking why `updateByPk` returning `0`